# Redirect a http request to a specific IP and port in a Docker Container

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, iptables, docker

I am using a Docker container with an image based on `python:2.7-alpine`.
I would like to have all the requests to `ec2.us-west-2.amazonaws.com` to be redirected to `127.0.0.1:3000`.

How can I achieve that?

I am running a dummy AWS API endpoint locally in the container and I would like that all the requests to AWS EC2 go to my dummy endpoint on port 3000. Unfortunately, I cannot override the API endpoint, that is the reason because I am after a solution that may include IP tables and some hacks in the hosts file.

Comment: Plenty of web servers or reverse proxies can handle this, lighttpd, nginx, haproxy, to name a german couple.

Comment: ok are you able to show me an example of docker file using iptables? @GerardH.Pille

Comment: No, I meant to say that I would not use iptables to solve your problem.

Comment: Ok, can you show me how you would solve this problem in a Docker file?

Answer (score 0):

To let nginx act as a reverse proxy for your Docker container, you'd add the following to its config

```
server {
  server_name ec2.us-west-2.amazonaws.com;

  location / {
    proxy_pass_header Authorization;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection "";
    proxy_buffering off;
    client_max_body_size 0;
    proxy_read_timeout 36000s;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }
}
```

If you'd like to know what you're doing, have a look at https://www.techandme.se/set-up-nginx-reverse-proxy/